# Select Your Next Badge UI Element Misplaced

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

On the "Select your next badge" popup, the exit button is misplaced and written over the window title thusly:

[image: Misplaced UI Exit Button]

macOS: 11.4
Safari: 14.1.1

This behavior is present on SO and Meta.

Comment: This is because of a CSS change that just got pushed out, replacing the `grid--cell` class with `flex--item`. The problems you describe should repro on all browsers. A bunch of things broke with this change, most notably on the profile page. (Not to mention a bunch of userscripts that a number of us use to customize the site.) This change appears to have been little more than a global search-and-replace, with no testing whatsoever before it was deployed, as none of these side-effects were detected or fixed before it went live.

Comment: Can you add a link to that page (or alternatively, some navigation help)?

Comment: That a heavy bug.

Comment: @PeterMortensen From either SO or Meta, click on the badge count banner at the top of the page. From your user page, click on the gear icon next to "Next Badge". This will bring up the popup window above.

Comment: As of 2021-07-09, this seems to be fixed.