# Irregular badge summary formatting on profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

The following screen capture sums it up:

[image]

Have there been some recent UI changes to the site?  This screen capture was taken from my Android phone.

Comment: MSE parallel: [Badges information is messed up on user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367272/571958)

Comment: Different symptom, but same root cause as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409038/select-your-next-badge-ui-element-misplaced). Feel free to edit your screenshot into that question, too, to emphasize how widespread the effects are.