# Style bug: "Select your next badge" window overlapping close button

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

The close button on the "select your badge" window overlaps with the word "badge". This was not an issue, at least for me, before today.

[image: Screenshot of the "Select your next badge" window, showing the issue.]

System notes:
OS: Windows 10
Web browser: Chrome 91.0.4472.124

Comment: *Very likely* the same root cause as [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409038/select-your-next-badge-ui-element-misplaced), but since I don't have time to confirm at the moment, I'm holding off on closing this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @CodyGray Not sure how I managed to miss that question when searching on Meta before posting, but thanks.

Comment: Don't feel bad! It's not exactly easy to search for these types of things. And I suspect this will unfortunately not be the last of many bug reports noting various site UI elements that are negatively affected by these recent changes.